# Checkbox arrays looping issue

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have 5 checkboxs, my array has 3 elements if the array element same as checkbox value then that checkbox checked but it should print only one time

```
<?php
$selvals = array("Manhattan", "Bronx", "Brooklyn");
    $myArray = explode(',', $selvals);
    foreach($myArray as $i)
    {

    ?>

    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($i == "Manhattan"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="manhattan" value="Manhattan" >Manhattan</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($i == "Bronx"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="bronx" value="Bronx" >Bronx</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($i == "Brooklyn"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="brooklyn" value="Brooklyn" >Brooklyn</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($i == "Queens"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="queen" value="Queens" >Queens</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($i == "Staten Island"){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="staten" value="Staten Island" >Staten Island</label>

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should be like this:- :)

```
<?php
$selvals = array("Manhattan", "Bronx", "Brooklyn");
?>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("Manhattan",$selvals)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="manhattan" value="Manhattan" >Manhattan</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("Bronx",$selvals)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="bronx" value="Bronx" >Bronx</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("Brooklyn",$selvals)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="brooklyn" value="Brooklyn" >Brooklyn</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("Queens",$selvals)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="queen" value="Queens" >Queens</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("Staten Island",$selvals)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> name="staten" value="Staten Island" >Staten Island</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of your `explode` function should be a string. But you don't need it, just remove the explode statement and replace the `$myArray` with `$selvals` in the loop.

```
$selvals = array("Manhattan", "Bronx", "Brooklyn");
foreach ($selvals as $i)
         ^^^^^^^
```